# Passing values from rest API to form using SwiftForms

Tags: ios, swift, forms

I've created the form I describe below using Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7 and Swiftforms project but I don't Know why the print(name) and the print(email) are nil the result of the call of the  Client.Service.getId()  function its ok and not nil.

```
class AccountViewController: FormViewController {

  let Client = Client()

  var users: [User]?
  var name: String?
  var email: String?

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Client.Service.getId() { users, error in

      if users != nil {
        self.users = users
        if self.users?.count != 0
        {
          self.loadForm()
          self.name = self.users![0].name// IS NOT NIL
          self.email = self.users![0].email// IS NOT NIL
        }
      } else {
        print("error: \(error)")
      }

    }
  }

  private func loadForm() {

   let form = FormDescriptor()

    form.title = "Example Form"

    let section1 = FormSectionDescriptor()


     var row: FormRowDescriptor! = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.emailTag, rowType: .Email, title: "Email")
     row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.CellConfiguration] = ["textField.placeholder" : "john@gmail.com", "textField.textAlignment" : NSTextAlignment.Right.rawValue]
     row.value = self.email
    print(email) ////IS NIL
     section1.addRow(row)


     row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.nameTag, rowType: .Name, title: "Name")
     row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.CellConfiguration] = ["textField.placeholder" : "Miguel Angel Ortuño", "textField.textAlignment" : NSTextAlignment.Right.rawValue]
     row.value = self.name
    print(name)///IS NILL
     section1.addRow(row)

     row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.phoneTag, rowType: .Phone, title: "Phone")
     row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.CellConfiguration] = ["textField.placeholder" : "e.g. 0034666777999", "textField.textAlignment" : NSTextAlignment.Right.rawValue]
     section1.addRow(row)

    let section2 = FormSectionDescriptor()


     row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.birthday, rowType: .Date, title: "Birthday")
     section2.addRow(row)

     row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.picker, rowType: .Picker, title: "Gender")
     row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = ["F", "M", "U"]
     row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.TitleFormatterClosure] = { value in
      switch( value ) {
      case "F":
        return "Female"
      case "M":
        return "Male"
      case "U":
        return "I'd rather not to say"
      default:
        return nil
      }
      } as TitleFormatterClosure

     row.value = "M"


     section2.addRow(row)


    let section3 = FormSectionDescriptor()


     section3.headerTitle = "Push Notifications"

     row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.enabled, rowType: .BooleanSwitch, title: "Enable")

     section3.addRow(row)


    let section4 = FormSectionDescriptor()


     section4.headerTitle = "Privacy"

     row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.categories, rowType: .MultipleSelector, title: "Profile")
     row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = [0, 1, 2]
     row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.AllowsMultipleSelection] = true
     row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.TitleFormatterClosure] = { value in
      switch( value ) {
      case 0:
        return "Public"
      case 1:
        return "Friend"
      case 2:
        return "Me"
      default:
        return nil
      }
      } as TitleFormatterClosure

     section4.addRow(row)

     row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.categories, rowType: .MultipleSelector, title: "Activity")
     row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = [0, 1, 2]
     row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.AllowsMultipleSelection] = true
     row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.TitleFormatterClosure] = { value in
      switch( value ) {
      case 0:
        return "Public"
      case 1:
        return "Friend"
      case 2:
        return "Me"
      default:
        return nil
      }
      } as TitleFormatterClosure

     section4.addRow(row)


     form.sections = [section1, section2, section3, section4]

     self.form = form
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Client.Service.getId()` communicates with a server and therefore it's a async operation. At the time you call `loadForm()`, the data from the server has not arrived yet, so `email` and `name` outside the callback function will be `nil`.

You could simply call `loadForm()` inside `Client.Service.getId()`'s callback.
Additionally, you must set the `form` property before `viewDidLoad()` is called.

```
class AccountViewController: FormViewController {

 let Client = Client()

 var users: [User]?
 var name: String?
 var email: String?

 override public var form = FormDescriptor()

 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)

 }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   Client.Service.getId() { users, error in

     if users != nil {
       self.users = users
       if self.users?.count != 0 {

         self.name = self.users![0].name// IS NOT NIL
         self.email = self.users![0].email// IS NOT NIL
         self.loadForm()
       }
     } else {
       print("error: \(error)")
     }
   }
 }

 private func loadForm() {
   // Since we already set it, no need to do it again
   // let form = FormDescriptor()

   self.form.title = "Example Form"

   /*
     ...
   */
   self.form.sections = [section1, section2, section3, section4]
 }
}
```

Comment: I edited my code with your suggestion and Im getting an error `assertion failed: self.form property MUST be assigned!`

Answer (score 0):

You should call loadForm() inside **service's callback**, Client.Service.getId()'s. With most of using services, you should use that ways.